Ruby langchainrb gem and custom configuration for the model setup
I am working in a prototype using the gem langchainrb. I am using the module assistant module to implemente a basic RAG architecture.
Everything works, and now I would like to customize the model configuration.
In the documenation there is no clear way of setting up the Model. In my case, I would like to use OpenAi and use:

temperature: 0.1
Model: gpt-4o

In the README, there is a mention about using llm_options.
If I go to the OpenAI Module documentation:

https://rubydoc.info/gems/langchainrb/Langchain/LLM/OpenAI

It says I have to check here:

https://github.com/alexrudall/ruby-openai/blob/main/lib/openai/client.rb#L5-L13

But there is not any mention of temperature, for example. Also, in the example in the Langchain::LLM::OpenAI documentation, the options are totally different.
# ruby-openai options:

CONFIG_KEYS = %i[
  api_type
  api_version
  access_token
  log_errors
  organization_id
  uri_base
  request_timeout
  extra_headers
].freeze

# Example in Class: Langchain::LLM::OpenAI documentation: 

{
  n: 1,
  temperature: 0.0,
  chat_completion_model_name: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
  embeddings_model_name: "text-embedding-3-small"
}.freeze


Langchain.rb version: 0.13.4


I added an issue in the github repo but I think here is a better way to solve my issue.

You appear to be conflating the llm_options with the default_options. The first list is the llm_options and the second is the default_options. The method signature is def initialize(api_key:, llm_options: {}, default_options: {})

@engineersmnky answer added thanks to your guidance

@engineersmnky is right on their comment.
I have a conflict between llm_options and default_options. I thought it was the same with different priorities.
For the needs expressed in the question I have to use the default_options as in here:
llm =
  Langchain::LLM::OpenAI.new(
    api_key: <OPENAI_KEY>,
    default_options: {
      temperature: 0.0,
      chat_completion_model_name: "gpt-4o"
    }
  )

